# Deploying 'dydxprotocol / solo' results "Error: spawnSync /bin/sh ENOBUFS"

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, truffle-deployment

I'm running in Amazon cloud9
https://github.com/dydxprotocol/solo
running 'npm run deploy_test'
At some point of the contracts compilation (maybe the end) I get the ENOBUFS error.
Is that something in the host that results with the ENOBUFS?
Is that something in the solidity compiler?

> Compiling ./contracts/testing/TokenC.sol
> Compiling canonical-weth/contracts/WETH9.sol
> Compiling openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/GSN/Context.sol
> Compiling openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
> Compiling openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol
> Compiling openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol
> Error: spawnSync /bin/sh ENOBUFS
> at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1083:20)
> at spawnSync (node:child_process:812:24)
> at execSync (node:child_process:895:15)
> at Object.compile (/home/ec2-user/environment/git/exchange-wrappers/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/compilerSupplier/loadingStrategies/Docker.js:19:1)
> at invokeCompiler (/home/ec2-user/environment/git/exchange-wrappers/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:257:1)
> at run (/home/ec2-user/environment/git/exchange-wrappers/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:29:40)
> Truffle v5.1.28 (core: 5.1.28)
> Node v16.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to work around it by calling each step in the script.

```
"deploy_test": "npm run reset_test_evm && npm run migrate -- --network test --reset && npm run snapshot_test_evm && npm run clean_contract_json",
"reset_test_evm": "node scripts/reset-test-evm.js",
"migrate": "truffle migrate",
"snapshot_test_evm": "node scripts/snapshot-test-evm.js",
"clean_contract_json": "ts-node ./scripts/CleanBuild.ts",
```

So I called:

- npm run reset_test_evm
- truffle migrate --network test --reset

Now I'm stuck again due to:

> "OperationImpl" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail.

But that's a matter for a different question...